# MySQL INSERT SELECT not Inserting

Tags: mysql

I am trying tor un an insert select that looks like this:

```
INSERT INTO users_extension_usage (userid, extensionid, complete) 
SELECT '3', extensions.id FROM extensions WHERE extensions.folder='definitions', '1'
```

however it has a problem when I run it in phpMyAdmin that refers to the '1':

```
#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ' '1'' at line 2
```

I have tried many different combinations of SELECT, INSERT etc but I cat see the problem. I have looked at any different posts on here and other forums too but alas most suggest the syntax I am using!

I have tried to set up an SQL Fiddle here: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/9f460

Any suggestions for how this might work will be gratefully accepted :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are missing the third column:

```
INSERT INTO users_extension_usage(userid, extensionid, complete) 
    SELECT '3', extensions.id, '1' as complete
    FROM extensions
    WHERE extensions.folder = 'definitions';
```

The `'1'` belongs in the `SELECT` statement, not after the `WHERE`.

Comment: Hi Gordon. Thanks very much, that works... but it confuses me a little. Why do we need to define '1' as complete, but not '3' as userid?

Comment: @user2037165 . . . The aliases make no difference.  I just added the alias to clarify what the value was being used for (and ironically, my attempt at clarify seems to have caused further confusion).