# How to insert one query result to another query as an input

Tags: mysql, node.js

When I try to run a query I am getting 500 Internal Error. I want to insert `query2` result to `query` as a data.

Query:

```
exports.create = async (req, res) => {
  try {
  const connection = await mysql.createConnection(config.mysql.credentials);
  var query2='select MAX(orders) from pdb_product';
  const query = `insert into pdb_product (product_code, description, active, third_party, 
  orders) values ("${req.body.product_code}", "${req.body.description}", ${(req.body.active == 'on' ? 1 : 0)}, ${(req.body.third_party == 'on' ? 1 : 0)}, ${query2});`;
  await connection.query(query);
  res.redirect('/products');
  } catch (e) {
    utils.error500(req, res, e.message);
  }
  };
```

The error I am getting:

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'select MAX(orders) from pdb_product)' at line 1

How can I resolve this?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [MySQL INSERT SELECT not Inserting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35762840/mysql-insert-select-not-inserting)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are missing a '(' bracket before the query2 parameter:

```
const query = `insert into pdb_product (product_code, description, active, third_party, 
  orders) 
values ("${req.body.product_code}", 
    "${req.body.description}", 
     ${(req.body.active == 'on' ? 1 : 0)}, 
     ${(req.body.third_party == 'on' ? 1 : 0)}, 
     (${query2}));`;
```

Comment: when I run your query, `You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 1'`error

Comment: Sorry, I added line breaks to make the SQL in the answer more readable - you should remove them

Comment: I added them without breaks. But your query is not correct. If we put such `(` before `query2` , how `(` after values bracket closes?

Comment: My mistake I missed the ending bracket. `${query2}` needs to be surrounded by `(` and `)`

Comment: I used that also. But it is not working mate. :( . `You can't specify target table 'pdb_product' for update in FROM clause`

Comment: Try changing query2: `var query2='select MAX(orders) from (select * from pdb_product) as prod';`

Comment: This workes perfectly. Thank you for your guidance and assistance.